# Ошибка функции при передаче аргумента

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть часть логики (отправка [`InlineKeyboardButton`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) в чат):

```
public function count(){
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $this->buttons($res = ($a + $b))
}

public function buttons($res)
{
    $inline_keyboard = [
            'inline_keyboard' => [
                [
                    [
                        'text' => $res,
                        'callback_data' => 'ok'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    return "&reply_markup=" . json_encode($inline_keyboard);
}
```

Так вот проблема в том, что, используя `$res = ($a + $b)` в качестве аргумента для `buttons()` - ошибка `500`, используя `$res = "'".($a + $b)."'"` - получаю кнопку с текстом `'3'`. Хочу все-таки просто `3`. Не могу понять, в чем проблема.

**UPD**:
`'text' => ''.$equationResult.'',` - так сработало. Но почему?!

Comment: `$res = $a + $b; $this->buttons($res);` ?

Comment: @br3t пробовал, не помогло. Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: У вас была одна проблема - присваивание внутри вызова функции, а по факту ещё и зацепилось требование в 'text' передачи строки.

Comment: @br3t понял, спасибо. Мое "решение" - насколько адекватно?

Comment: Товарищи рекомендуют `(string)` или `strval` как более явные способы приведения к строке. С ними в дальнейшем будет более понятно, что там происходит.

Comment: Плюс достаточно сконкатенировать со строкой с одной стороны `'' . $var`